# php foreach and positions

Tags: php, foreach

**php**

```
$new_position = $_POST['new_position'];
$new_positionpieces = explode(",", $new_position);
foreach ($new_positionpieces as $value) {
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

`cat_37<br>cat_36<br>`

From what I gather if I were to `echo $new_positionpieces[0]` it would say `cat_37`

How would I be able to get that 0 into a variable inside my `foreach` so that If it were something like

`echo $item.' - '.$value.'<br>';`
and outputs `0 - cat_37` so that I am able to put it into my db

Comment: `foreach($haystack as $key => $value)`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($new_positionpieces as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . "=" . $value . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Just remember if you are going to use the $key or $value for an insert query or printing to the screen make sure you escape them.

Comment: @OliverBS, that's good general advice, but the question doesn't mention how he's going to use the keys and values.

Comment: Yeah true, just noticed he edited the question and mentioned he was putting it in a DB :)

Comment: Oh yes I see.  Then yeah, it's important to do that in a safe manner (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).